# Вывод бинарного дерева на консоль

Tags: c++, linux

Имеется бинарное дерево из целых чисел. Просмотр дерева требуется организовать в консоли. Использую gnome-terminal. Подскажите, какие есть способы выводить дерево на консоль, чтобы оно было "похоже на дерево". Ну например как при вызове pstree в linux. Или другие виды, главное чтобы видно было где родитель, а какие от него исходят дети.

Comment: Здесь посмотрите: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965335/how-to-print-binary-tree-diagram

Comment: А есть что похожее, только на С/С++? Java пока не освоил(

Comment: @carapuz а Вам и не надо осваивать Java чтобы прочитать этот код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Pretty Print a Binary Tree](http://www.leetcode.com/2010/09/how-to-pretty-print-binary-tree.html)

> Wouldn’t it be cool to output your binary tree like this?